# Reversing range-based for loop on a custom container class

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, c++14, reverse-iterator

I'm trying to improve my C++ skills by porting the major examples in *Algorithms, 4th Edition* by Sedgewick and Wayne. I wrote a generic stack implementation based on their Java [example](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/ResizingArrayStack.java.html).

My stack works fine, but I'd like to make a performance improvement and got stuck trying to write a reverse iterator.

```
template<typename T> class ResizingArrayStack {
public:
    T* begin() { return &array_ptr[0]; }
    T* end() { return &array_ptr[N]; }
```

...

```
// Here we're iterating forward through the array, with an unused variable `i`.
// It would be nice performance-wise to iterate in reverse without calling pop(), and without triggering a resize.
for ( auto& i : lifo_stack ) {
    cout << "Current loop iteration has i = " << i << endl;
}
// // Alternatively, pop from the stack N times.
// cout << "Popped an item from the stack: " << lifo_stack.pop() << endl;
```

I tried switching the `begin` and `end` member functions above, but found that the expanded for-loop always increments with `++__begin`, even if `__end` is at a lower memory address. How can we get `i` to loop in reverse (LIFO with respect to the stack)?

Please feel free to comment on my code style if there are egregious errors or aspects that look out of date. I want stay in-line with good 'modern' C++.

Comment: [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator#Example)

Comment: Maybe have a look at the implementation of `std::rbegin`, `std::rend`.

Comment: [range v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) has `reverse_view`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the range-for loop with reverse iterators, you can use a wrapper class `Reverse` that stores a range and returns the `reverse_iterator`s corresponding to `begin` and `end`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<class Rng>
class Reverse
{
    Rng const& rng;    
public:    
    Reverse(Rng const& r) noexcept
    : 
        rng(r)
    {}

    auto begin() const noexcept { using std::end; return std::make_reverse_iterator(end(rng)); }
    auto end()   const noexcept { using std::begin; return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin(rng)); }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> my_stack;
    my_stack.push_back(1);
    my_stack.push_back(2);
    my_stack.push_back(3);

    // prints 3,2,1
    for (auto const& elem : Reverse(my_stack)) {
        std::cout << elem << ',';    
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7MoSZOe8fzrMD8gi)

Note that this uses C++1z template deduction, only supported by g++ 7.0 SVN and clang 5.0 SVN. For earlier compilers you could add a helper function

```
    template<class Rng>
    auto MakeReverse(Rng const& rng) { return Reverse<Rng>(rng); }

    for (auto const& elem : MakeReverse(my_stack)) {
        std::cout << elem << ',';    
    }
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/N69AwOJzcrJ5qIWC) (works as of gcc 5.1 or clang 3.5)

Alternatively, you can use the [**Boost.Range library**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html) and simply do (will work any C++11 compiler)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> my_stack;
    my_stack.push_back(1);
    my_stack.push_back(2);
    my_stack.push_back(3);

    for (auto const& elem : boost::adaptors::reverse(my_stack)) {
        std::cout << elem << ',';    
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GeKne9L3ykQJDJPw)

Note that you have to be careful about passing temporary variables to such adaptors, both mine and the Boost adaptor do not work when passing e.g. a raw `std::vector<int>{3,2,1}`, as pointed out by @Pixelchemist in the comments.

Comment: Pre-C++1z, you can also do what `std` does pretty much everywhere else and introduce a `make_reverse` function template to do the decution for you.

Comment: 1. `for(auto i : MakeReverse(std::vector<int>{1,2,3})) { /* land of doom here */ }` aka "no rvalues possible". 2. Works only if `std::begin` and `std::end` 'work'. If you need adl-enabled `begin` and `end`, things get more complicated.

Comment: @Pixelchemist that's no worse than the Boost.Range adaptor `reverse`. Are you holding me to a higher standard? :) Updated, though.

Comment: Neither do I know nor use boost.range but if that adaptor captures rvalues and holds them by reference or saves iterators of an rvalue, then I'd consider it somewhat broken or at least dangerous. `for(auto i : make_vector(1,2,3)){ ... }` is perfectly valid so I wouldn't expect `for(auto i : reverse(make_vector(1,2,3))){ ... }` to lead into undefined behaviourland.

Comment: @Pixelchemist well for boost it is, and so is my simple adaptor, but documented now, and the ADL thingy is also fixed.

Comment: @TemplateRex: A raw rvalue isn't quite frequent but functions returning ranges/containers by value are quite common as well as eligible. Thus, I think that a solution that properly handles rvalues but has no further overhead in the lvalue case is preferable.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough answer, but I wasn't able to get the Reverse wrapper class working even with the MakeReverse helper function (for < c++1z). I solved it my own way. Please feel free to tear my answer apart if you see issues with it.

Comment: @djwbrown I tested the code example links for C++11 / C++14 compatibility: the Boost.Range example works for C+11, and the MakeReverse for gcc 5.1 or clang 3.5. It requires [`make_reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator) that you could implement yourself using C++11 featurs only.

Comment: @TemplateRex Very useful and nice answer. However there is a small typo: In the first code sample you call `my_stack.puhs_back(3)`, so the 'h' and 's' are exchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Here a scratch for your problem. Don't consider this as working code. Use it to just get an idea of how reverse iterator MAY be implemented (just one many possible ways).

```
template<typename T> class ResizingArrayStack {
public: 
    class reverse_iterator
    {       
        ResizingArrayStack & _storage;
        int _pointer;

    public:
        inline reverse_iterator(ResizingArrayStack & storage,
                                int pointer)
            : _storage(storage)
            , _pointer(pointer)
        {}

        inline reverse_iterator & operator++() // prefix
        {
            --_pointer;
            return *this;
        }

        inline reverse_iterator operator++() // postfix
        {
            reverse_iterator tmp(*this);
            --_pointer;
            return tmp;
        }

        inline T & operator*()
        {
            return _storage.getByIndex(_pointer);
        }

        // TODO: == != etc
    };      

    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return reverse_iterator(*this, N - 1); }
    reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator(*this, -1); }
    // ...  //
};
```

Answer (score 1):

*This solution does not introduce unnecessary copies and does not exhibit incorrect forwarding as suggested by some comments. Explanation below.*

You can use some wrapper which has begin and end functions that actually 
return reverse iterators.

```
template<class T>
struct revert_wrapper
{
    T o;
    revert_wrapper(T&& i) : o(std::forward<T>(i)) {}
};

template<class T>
auto begin(revert_wrapper<T>& r)
{
    using std::end;
    return std::make_reverse_iterator(end(r.o));
}

template<class T>
auto end(revert_wrapper<T>& r)
{
    using std::begin;
    return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin(r.o));
}

template<class T>
auto begin(revert_wrapper<T> const& r) 
{ 
    using std::end;
    return std::make_reverse_iterator(end(r.o));
}

template<class T>
auto end(revert_wrapper<T> const& r)
{
    using std::begin;
    return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin(r.o));
}

template<class T>
auto reverse(T&& ob)
{
    return revert_wrapper<T>{ std::forward<T>(ob) };
}
```

Used like this:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
for (auto i : reverse(v))
{
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

or in your case

```
for ( auto& i : reverse(lifo_stack) ) {
    cout << "Current loop iteration has i = " << i << endl;
    cout << "Popped an item from the stack: " << lifo_stack.pop() << endl;
}
```

---

Since fowarding is not an easy topic and there is misconception around I'll further explain some details. I'll use `std::vector<int>` as an example for the "to be reversed" type `T`.

### 1.  The function template `reverse`.

#### 1.1 Passing an lvalue `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto&& x = reverse(v);
```

The compiler created instance of `reverse` in this case would look like:

```
template<>
auto reverse<std::vector<int>&>(std::vector<int>& ob)
{
    return revert_wrapper<std::vector<int>&>{ std::forward<std::vector<int>&>(ob) };
}
```

We see two things here:

- The `T` of `revert_wrapper` will be `std::vector<int>&`, so no copy involved.
- we're forwarding an lvalue as an lvalue to the constructor of `revert_wrapper`

#### 1.2 Passing an rvalue `std::vector<int>`

```
std::vector<int> foo();
auto&& x = reverse(foo());
```

We look again at the instantiation of the function template:

```
template<>
auto reverse<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>&& ob)
{
    return revert_wrapper<std::vector<int>>{ std::forward<std::vector<int>>(ob) };
}
```

And can again note two things:

- The `T` of `revert_wrapper` will be `std::vector<int>`, thus copy the vector, preventing the rvalue from going out of scope before any range based loop can run
- an rvalue `std::vector<int>&&` will be forwarded to the constructor of `revert_wrapper`

### 2. The class template `revert_wrapper` and its constructor

#### 2.1 The `revert_wrapper` created by `reverse` in case of an lvalue `std::vector<int>&`

```
template<>
struct revert_wrapper<std::vector<int>&>
{
    std::vector<int>& o;
    revert_wrapper(std::vector<int>& i) : 
        o(std::forward<std::vector<int>&>(i)) {}
};
```

As noted above: No copies involved as we store a reference.
The `forward` also seems familiar and indeed it is just the same as above within `reverse`: We forward an lvalue as lvalue reference.

#### 2.2 The `revert_wrapper` created by `reverse` in case of an rvalue `std::vector<int>&&`

```
template<>
struct revert_wrapper<std::vector<int>>
{
    std::vector<int> o;
    revert_wrapper(std::vector<int>&& i) : 
        o(std::forward<std::vector<int>>(i)) {}
};
```

This time we have the object stored by value to prevent a dangling reference. 
Also the forwarding is fine: We forwarded the rvalue reference from `reverse` to the `revert_wrapper` constructor and we forward it on to the `std::vector` constructor. We could've used `static_cast<T&&>(i)` in the same way but we're not `(std::)mov(e)`ing from an lvalue, we're forwarding:

- lvalues as lvalues and
- rvalues as rvalues.

We can also see one more thing here:
The only available constructor of the `revert_wrapper` instance that stores by value takes an rvalue. Therefore, we can't (easily) trick this class to make unnecessary copies.

**Note that replacing `std::forward` with `std::move` inside the initializer of `o` in the `revert_wrapper` constructor would actually be wrong.**

Comment: it seams that `reverse()` makes a copy of the entire container

Comment: @sp2danny: No. The deduced, forwarding reference of `reverse` will make `T` a reference type if an lvalue is passed. If an rvalue is passed, `revert_wrapper` will store the object by value (which makes indeed sense since a reference would dangle otherwise).

Comment: @TemplateRex: No. The deduction is done in `reverse` which creates the correct template instance. If an lvalue (i.e. `U&`) is passed to `reverse` then `T`= `U&` and `revert_wrapper` holds a reference. If an rvalue (`U&&`) is passed to `reverse` then `T` = `U` and `revert_wrapper` holds the item by value.

Comment: I am talking about the `revert_wrapper` constructor

Comment: @TemplateRex: `std::forward` is a cast to `T&&` which is in case of an lvalue `T&` through reference collapsing and in case of an rvalue `T&&` which looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: it would certainly be more idiomatic to use `std::move` in that place.

Comment: @TemplateRex: `std::move` can not be used here because the result of `std::move` in case of `T` being an lvalue reference isn't an lvalue reference but an rvalue reference and this is not what we want. The constructor is forwarding to the member. The deduction is not happening in place (shifted up the calltree instead) but we're still forwarding here. Using `std::move` would result in an error like "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type `T&` from an rvalue of type `T`."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135669/discussion-between-pixelchemist-and-templaterex).

Answer (score 1):

once you have functioning (regular) iterators, 
implement reverse iterators using the standard library
helper class template `std::reverse_iterator`

```
#include <iterator>

class XX { 

    // your code

    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;

    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return reverse_iterator{end()}; }
    reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator{begin()}; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your full code`lifo_stack.pop()` invalidates your iterators, so it cannot be used inside a *ranged for*. You have **Undefined Behavior**

Moreover it doesn't make much sense to use a *range for* for a stack. If you can iterate over its elements then it's not a stack now isn't it? A stack has the property that you can **only** access the most recent inserted element.

---

Based on your comment:

> Consider the case where you add items slowly and individually, but
>   wish to dump them out of the stack as quickly as possible. I don't
>   want the overhead of copying and resizing arrays which pop() would
>   trigger at that moment.

I still think that ranged-for does not make sense for a stack.

Here is how I see your problem solved:

```
lifo_stack.disable_resizing(); // prevents resizing 
while (!lifo_stack.is_empty()
{
    lifo_stack.pop(); // maybe use the poped element
}
lifo_stack.enable_resizing(); // re-enables resizing and triggers a resize
```

If you don't need the popped elements and just want to emtpy the stack, there is a faster way (based on your class implementation):

```
// empties the stack
void clear()
{
   delete[] array_ptr;
   array_ptr = new T[1];;
   max_size = 1;
   N = 0;
}
```

One last final though if you want to use modern C++ then use `unique_ptr` instead of manual `new` and `delete`. It is easier but most importantly **safer**. And read on the rule of 0/3/5.

Comment: I don't think a stack necessary means you cannot access all elements. A stack's primary property is that you can only push and pop.

Comment: @Angew "A stack's primary property is that you can only push and pop" Correct. Which means that you can only access the element returned by pop which is the most recently pushed element in  a stack. That means that you cannot iterate over it's elements (like in a ranged for).

Comment: You're right, I should have removed the lifo_stack.pop() from this example. It mutates the data structure over which I'm iterating which is _bad_. That said, I don't think it's unreasonable to iterate over a stack, as long as it happens in LIFO order. Consider the case where you add items slowly and individually, but wish to dump them out of the stack as quickly as possible. I don't want the overhead of copying and resizing arrays which pop() would trigger at that moment. The stack example is loosely based on this one (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/ResizingArrayStack.java.html).

Comment: @bolov The number of times I've needed an "iterable container where insertions and removals are only possible on one end" is *far* greater than the number of times I've needed a "stack where you can only access the topmost element." Hence, for me, an iterable stack makes sense. I claim the defining property of the stack is how you can *modify* it, not how you can *read* it.

Comment: @Angew that is definitely a very useful container. It's not a stack however. At least not in the strict definition.

Comment: @Angew and in his example he tried to iterate **and** modify the container.

Answer (score 1):

*Please see an excellent answer from TemplateRex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42221591/1615035).* I was able to solve the problem without a wrapper class, so I'll give a shot at answering my own question.

Here is the most helpful [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator#Example) I found on implementing iterators at http://en.cppreference.com, and you can find my updated ResizingArrayStack code at the same GitHub [link](https://github.com/djwbrown/algorithms-sedgewick-wayne/blob/master/src/lifo-stack-resizing-array.cpp) as found the question.

```
template<typename T> class ResizingArrayStack {
public:

    //----- Begin reversed iteration section -----//
    // Please see the example here, (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator).
    // Member typedefs inherit from std::iterator.
    class stackIterator: public std::iterator<
                        std::input_iterator_tag,   // iterator_category
                        T,                         // value_type
                        T,                         // difference_type
                        const T*,                  // pointer
                        T                          // reference
                        >{
        int index = 0;
        T* it_ptr = nullptr;
    public:
        // Prefix ++, equal, unequal, and dereference operators are the minimum required for range based for-loops.
        stackIterator(int _index = 0, T* _it_ptr = nullptr) { index = _index; it_ptr = _it_ptr; }
        // Here is where we reverse the sequence.
        stackIterator& operator++() { --index; return *this; }
        bool operator==(stackIterator other) { return index == other.index; }
        bool operator!=(stackIterator other) { return !( *this == other ); }
        T operator*() { return it_ptr[index-1]; }
    };

    stackIterator begin() { return stackIterator(N, array_ptr); }
    stackIterator end() {
        N = 0;  // 'Empty' the array.
        max_size = 1;  // Don't waste time calling resize() now. 
        return stackIterator(0, array_ptr);
    }
    //----- End reversed iteration section -----//

private:
    // Allocate space for a traditional array on the heap.
    T* array_ptr = new T[1];
    // Keep track of the space allocated for the array, max_size * sizeof(T).
    int max_size = 1;
    // Keep track of the current number of items on the stack.
    int N = 0;
```

Calling code where the range based for-loop iterates in reversed (or LIFO) order by default.

```
// It's nice performance-wise to iterate in reverse without calling pop() or triggering a resize.
for ( auto i : lifo_stack) {
    cout << "Current loop iteration has i = " << i << endl;
}
```