# "Nested" class-template argument deduction with parentheses: GCC vs. clang

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, c++17

Related, but (IMHO) different: [Nested template argument deduction for class templates not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244250/nested-template-argument-deduction-for-class-templates-not-working)

The following C++17 code is rejected from GCC 8, but clang compiles it without any issues. The GCC's error message is included as a comment just before the problematic line.

Which compiler is correct here?

https://godbolt.org/z/WG6f7G

```
template<class T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(T) {}
};

template<class T>
struct Bar {
     Bar(T) {};
};

void works() {
    Bar bar{1};// {}
    Foo foo(bar);// ()
}

void works_too() {
    Foo foo{Bar{1}};// {{}}
}

void error_in_gcc() {
// error: 'auto' parameter not permitted in this context
    Foo foo(Bar{1});// ({})
}

void but_this_works() {
    Foo(Bar{1});// ({})
}
```

Comment: Definite gcc bug. Pretty sure I filed something like this but can't find it right now.

Comment: @Barry Are you talking about https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87709

Comment: I suspect paring bug of gcc (parsing it a function declaration).

Comment: @Rakete1111 Found it, [81486](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81486). But that was _only_ for `()`, not for a specific argument.

Comment: Filed [89062](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89062).

Comment: @Rakete1111 Actually in retrospect, it might be the same bug as 87709

Comment: GCC gives even more confusing errors for `Foo f(Bar(x) / 1);` (with suitably declared `x` and `operator/`). Apparently GCC does not realize that this cannot be a valid function declaration (until it's too late).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments to this question state that this is a GCC bug. It has been filed as GCC bug report [89062](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89062).